# 3d maths in Flash AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, math, 3d

I'm trying to code a 3d wall like
http://www.flashloaded.com/flashcomponents/3dwall/

The shape I am looking to create is like a bath or arena where it is a curve cornered rectangle with sloping sides.

The image below shows what i'm trying to achieve if viewed from above. I hope that helps.

[image]

Can anyone give me some ideas on the maths to create this shape using primitive rectangle shapes.

Thanks,
Josh

Comment: Is your question about how to do tridimensional graphics ? Or is it about how to layout your rectangle as a nice curve ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix

http://www.devmaster.net/wiki/Transformation_matrices

A rectangle has 4 3D points (vectors)

> Define a vector this way
>   [image]

To move/rotate/scale just multiply each vector by the transformation matrix.

> This matrix rotates around X-axis:
>   [image]

For perpective projection (camera) look at: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection

For example: you can create rectangles and rotate them around an axis to create a cylinder like this:
[image]
<sub>(source: [flashloaded.com](http://www.flashloaded.com/flashcomponents/3dwall/images/3.jpg))</sub>

> your pit:
>   note: the angle is not correct, it should be pi-a (180º-a)
>   [image]
>
> create all rectangles centered at origin (0,0,0), then rotate them as needed and move to desired position. I recommend you to code the matrix routines first like rotate(), move(), scale() and a simple paint function (just line drawing, without perspective) the rest is just playing with the matrices.

Comment: thanks for this but i need a little bit of help in understanding what i should be doing. have you got any examples of how i can use a matrix to layout my rectangles.

Comment: i'm not sure on what you mean by "curve cornered rectangle with sloping sides". Can you draw a sketch?

Comment: thank you this is all very helpful - i just need to try and figure how to put it all together.